# Regex with optional, lazy, greedy group

Tags: regex

Let's take this source string from a word document:

```
A;SDLFJA;SDJFA;KSDJF;ALKSJDF SOURCE: 3 55 ASDKLFJA;KDSJF
sa;ldkjfa SOURCE: HYPERLINK "ASDLFA;SDFA;SKD" "MATCH9" 3 HYPERLINK   
"ASDLFA;SDFA;SKD" "MATCH10" 55 a;sdkfja;ksdfj;aklsdjf;lk
```

I'm looking for a pattern that is composed of the literal text "SOURCE: " followed by a 1 digit number a space and a 2 digit number.

For example, in the first line of the source string, I want to find "SOURCE: 3 55".

Now, some clever boffin has decided to embed a hyperlink for the 1 digit number and another hyperlink for the 2 digit number.  Lines 2 and 3 show the two embedded hyperlinks.  MATCH1 refers to the first embedded hyperlink, MATCH2 is the second, and so on.  I have no way of knowing how many hyperlinks will be placed before these, so one can't assume MATCH9 and MATCH10.

The text I want to extract is the "3 55" portion.  I want to put it into a named group I'll call "KeepMe".

I don't mind using two different patterns, one for the hyperlink and one without.

Here's a pattern that works for the non-hyperlinked text:

```
SOURCE:\s+(?<KeepMe>\d*\s+\d*)
```

I get "3 55" in the KeepMe group just like I want.

I haven't been able to keep the hyperlink match pattern from being greedy.

Here's a failed regex pattern, (one of many):

```
SOURCE:\s+(?<Hyperlink>HYPERLINK.*MATCH\d*\u0022\s+)??(?<KeepMe1>\d*)\s+
(?<Hyperlink>HYPERLINK.*MATCH\d*\u0022\s+)??(?<KeepMe2>\d*)
```

In the above pattern, I'm trying to say:

Look for the literal SOURCE: followed by one or more spaces.
Then, optionally look for the literal text "HYPERLINK followed by some characters, followed by the literal text MATCH, followed by some digits and a double quote character in a lazy, non-greedy manner, followed by one or more spaces, followed by some digits I want to keep.  Then, do another HYPERLINK pattern match like we just did and keep the digits after that, too.

Remember, in both cases, I want to extract "3 55".  It can be extracted in one or two pieces though one would be best.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

A Regex that works for just the hyperlinked case is:

```
/(?<SourceToken>SOURCE:)            # Start with a source tag
\s+                                 # Followed by whitespace
(?<HyperlinkMatchGroup>             # Save the hyperlink & match combo.
(?<Hyperlink>                       # Save the hyperlink (to be discarded)
(?<HyperlinkToken>HYPERLINK\s+)     # Hyperlinks start with the literal tag "HYPERLINK"
(?<HyperlinkText>".*?")             # Hyperlink text contained in quotes, non-greedy
\s*)                                # Followed by whitespace
*                                   # Repeating any number of times
(?<MatchToken>"MATCH\d*")           # Followed by a literal tag "MATCH" and a digit string
\s*                                 # Followed by whitespace
(?<KeepMe>\d+)                      # Finally, the match, which is just a series of digits
\s*                                 # Followed by whitespace
)+                                  # The whole hyperlink & match pair must occur at least once
/x
```

It may or may not cover all your cases; I haven't spent much time digging into it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
\bSOURCE:\s+(?:HYPERLINK\s+"[^"]*"\s+"MATCH\d+"\s+)?(?<KeepMe1>\d+)\s+(?:HYPERLINK\s+"[^"]*"\s+"MATCH\d+"\s+)?(?<KeepMe2>\d+)\b
```

Main difference is that I replaced the `.*` between `HYPERLINK` and `MATCH` with something less greedy.

Fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/yE3fP4/1